# mkvirtualenv doesn't work (for Translate Toolkit)

Tags: windows, python

Following the Translate Toolkit [Installing on Windows](https://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/installation.html) guide, I get the message `bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found` in my git-bash, when trying to run `mkvirtualenv ttk`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Python[version]/Scripts` folder, which should be in your PATH.

In there, `mkvirtualenv.bat` is located.

The following command will work:

```
mkvirtualenv.bat ttk
```

The same is true for the command `workon`, used later in the guide. Use `workon.bat` instead.